# Increament multidimensional field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the best way to rename multidimensional HTML fields that increment the index by 1 using jQuery and regex?

**Sample HTML structure:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="children">
        <input type="text" name="user[1][name]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="Web Developer">
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <input type="text" name="user[1][name]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="Web Developer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Name structure `user[1][title]` or `user[1][title][]` where `user`, `[title]` or `[title][]` is any string name and `[1]` must increment by 1 when adding new children HTML.

**Output name must be in this format:**

```
user[1][name]
user[1][title][]
user[1][title][]

user[2][name]
user[2][title][]
user[2][title][]

user[3][name]
user[3][title][]
user[3][title][]
```

Working code sample:

```
$("#parent > .children").each(function(){
    var row = 1;                        

    $("[name]", this).each(function(){
        var name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)]*?\]/, '['+ row +']');
        this.name = name;
    });

    row++;
});
```

I need a regular expression that does not include the square bracket.

Comment: Um... `[user][name]`?

Comment: Did you try moving `row++;` to the `function()`'s body, right below `this.name = name;`? Also, the regex must look like `/\[\d*?\]/`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where in the process you're using this, but if you're adding these fields one at a time something like this may work:

```
$("#parent").append('<div class="children">');
var count = $(".children").length;
$($(".children")[count-1]).append('<input type="text" name="user[' + count + '][name]">');
$($(".children")[count-1]).append('<input type="checkbox" name="user[' + count + '][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">');
$($(".children")[count-1]).append('<input type="checkbox" name="user[' + count + '][title][]" value="Web Developer">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/23p2pusk/1/

Comment: This will not work because `user[1][name]` and `user[1][title][]` can be any string name. What i need is JavaScript regular expression to replace `[1]`, something like `this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)]*?\]/, '['+ row +']');`

Comment: I think I understand your question now. You have the HTML, but they all say the same thing: `user[1][name]` and you want them to increment. I will supply another answer...

Answer (score 0):

Run the snippet and check the source code, you'll see the names have been updated as expected.

```js
var count = $(".children").length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var inputs = $($(".children")[i]).children();
    $(inputs[0]).attr("name", "user[" + (i + 1) + "][name]");
    $(inputs[1]).attr("name", "user[" + (i + 1) + "][title][]");
    $(inputs[2]).attr("name", "user[" + (i + 1) + "][title][]");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="children">
        <input type="text" name="user[1][name]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="Web Developer">
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <input type="text" name="user[1][name]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="Web Developer">
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <input type="text" name="user[1][name]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="PHP Programmer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[1][title][]" value="Web Developer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like I said, this won’t work because the field name is not always `user[1][title][]` or `user[1][name]`. Please check the working example above.